# How to get a simple search bar with a search icon inside it

Tags: search, input, icons

I got a simple search bar and I want to add a simple png icon inside it

```
<input type="text" name="SearchBar" id="SearchBar"> // <--- I need a search icon here
<input type="image" id="SearchBar" src="images/buttons/submit.png">
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="searchtxt">
```

in `css` use the below code:

```
input.searchtxt
{
    background: url(../images/web.png) no-repeat; 
    float: right;
}
```